# MySQL Dump Error: Lost connection to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql, dump, ovh

I have a problem with my SQL database. 
My RAID failed but I recover data from the drive and now I have my old database, but it is full errors. I want to export it to SQL file and import it to new RAID and drives. ¨
But when I tried to dump it wit this command:

```
root@LFCZ:/home# mysqldump -u root -password mc | gzip -9 > mc.sql.gz
```

It gives me this Error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when using LOCK TABLES
```

Can you help with that? Only thing I need is to get .sql file. It is a very big database (approx. 13 GB) but It is running on OVH dedicated server, so it is powerfully enough.

Comment: r u able to read data through mysql queries...

Comment: Take a look at mysqls `REPAIR TABLE` feature. It solved a couple of issues for me in the past.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/470207/mysql-lost-connection-error-on-mysqldump

Comment: Zafar Malik Yes, I am. I can view the files.